# how do I know if my changes in elasticsearch.yml config file are reflecting or not? I have switched script.inline and script.indexed to true

Tags: elasticsearch

how do I know if my changes in the elasticsearch.yml config file are reflecting or not? I have added the following two lines and restarted elasticsearch.

> script.inline : true
>   script.indexed : true

I get the same error even on commenting out these two lines, when I run a "query" with "script" inline.

Attached screenshot of query and error message.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZ1jT.png)

Thanks

Comment: This might be error in your code try replacing doc with _doc

Comment: No. Did not help. And doc is an elasticsearch type to access elements of each index, as far as I understand. But thanks.

Comment: I know that doc stuff but in some contexts it didn’t work but _doc does any way have you restarted your cluster after changing.ymo file for those changes to take effect??

Comment: My elasticsearch is running on a docker container. I have restarted the whole container. It should have also restarted clusters.

Comment: Your are using mounted volume for es configurations or placed in dockerfile?

Comment: used one from https://www.docker.elastic.co/# to make my ES container.

Comment: Oh then your changes are not saved in elasticsearch

Comment: You need to do it by yourself container shell and do elasticsearch restart there after updating yml file to make these changes effective